# Run BASH command in JAVA in background

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, bash, jakarta-ee

I made a function that executes a command from BASH, and i want to make it run in background and never stop the execution of the main program.

I could use `screen -AmdS screen_thread123 php script.php` but the main ideea is that i learn and understand how threads work.

I have a basic knowledge about this, but right now i want to create a quick dynamic thread like the example of bellow :

```
public static void exec_command_background(String command) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

    List<String> listCommands = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] arrayExplodedCommands = command.split(" ");

    // it should work also with listCommands.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayExplodedCommands));
    for(String element : arrayExplodedCommands)
    {
        listCommands.add(element);
    }

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder(listCommands);

                ps.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process p = ps.start();

                p.waitFor();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

and it gives me this error

```
NologinScanner.java:206: error: local variable listCommands is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder(listCommands);
1 error
```

Why is that and how can i solve it? I mean how can i access the variable `listCommands` from this block?

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                // code here
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that inner class (and you don't want to `waitFor`)... just use

```
for(String element : arrayExplodedCommands)
{
    listCommands.add(element);
}
ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder(listCommands);

ps.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = ps.start();
// That's it.
```

As for your question of accessing the variable `listCommands` in your original block; make the reference final - like so

```
final List<String> listCommands = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, you don't have to wait for, but let's say i wanted to use threads, how the code will look like?

Comment: @Damian ProcessBuilder already runs in a separate thread for you. Note that you call `start()` on it.

Comment: I tested both. Work wonderfull. Thank you so muuch. I didn't used final before. What i know about final is that you can't change it anymore.

Comment: Can't change the reference. You can still add items to your `List`.

Comment: I read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java) and i quote `the final keyword is used in several different contexts to define an entity which cannot later be changed.` , perhaps you said that you can still add items to a `final` `List` i have to try some tests :)

Comment: @Damian You cannot reassign the list reference. So `listCommands = null;` would be illegal; you can add values to your List. Try it, but it'll work.

Comment: I understand now, i can add elements to it, but i cannot even reassign it like `List<String> list1 = new List<String>();`, right?